# Как реализовать систему оценки книг на сайте Django?

Tags: python, django

Учусь джанге, стоит задача реализовать систему оценок звездочками. Есть идея сделать сначала простую форму для записи оценки, для нее валидацию и сохранение данных в модели. Представляю, как сделать бесконечные оценки, не завязанные на авторизации пользователя. Однако хочу сделать так, чтобы каждый пользователь мог оставлять одну оценку.

Создала группу library members через админку, прописала шаблоны авторизации пользователей, однако не представляю, как сделать доступ к оценке каждому пользователю одноразово. Если пользователь уже поставил оценку, отображать ее, если нет, то отображать среднюю оценку остальных пользователей

Вот поля книг, авторов и жанров:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """ Модель, представляющая книги """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # ForeignKey использую, потому что книга может иметь только одного автора, но автор много книг
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Введите краткое описание книги')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13,
                            help_text='13 символова <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN номера</a> книги')
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', max_length=20, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class Author(models.Model):
    """ Модель представляет автора """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Genre(models.Model):
    """ Модель, представляющая жанры книг"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Введите жанр книги")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, чтобы дать пользователю голосовать только один раз за одну книгу, нужно создать модель оценки. То есть на каждую оценку пользователей будет создаваться отдельный объект. Также в модели книги нужно создать поле `рейтинг`, где будет храниться рейтинг каждой книги. Можно обойтись и без этого, но тогда при каждом запросе нужно будет фильтровать все объекты оценок и считать рейтинг - ненужная лишняя нагрузка.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    rating = rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

class Vote(models.Model):
    # можно сделать choices типа like/dislike или от одного до пяти, если звёзды будут, но это уже смотрите по ситуации
    value = models.SmallIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        # а вот эта команда и не даст повторно голосовать
        unique_together = ('user', 'book')
```

Осталось только написать подходящий view для создания оценки, куда внести проверку, что пользователь авторизован и проверку `value` чтобы не превышала определённое значение. Ну и если условия пройдены, то создаёте новую оценку и изменяете рейтинг нужной книги на значение оценки, типа

```
book.rating += rating
book.save()
```